# nuxtjs IE 11 polyfill-eventsource added missing EventSource to window

Tags: nuxt.js, internet-explorer-11

ie9：
Invalid HMR message: {"name":"client","action":"sync","time":557,"hash":"a0b4d086a83be953a239","warnings":[],"errors":[],"modules":{"0":"multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js","1":"zlib (ignored)","2":"fs (ignored)","3":"http (ignored)","4":"https (ignored)","5":"css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./layouts/error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=d5ea9138&scoped=true&lang=css&","6":"css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&","7":"css ./node_modules/css-loader/d

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOvd3.png

```
nuxt.js@2.14.12

{
  "presets": [
[
  "env",
  {
    "modules": false,
    "useBuiltIns": "entry"
  }
],
  "stage-3"
]}

"@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
"babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",

poly.js
import 'babel-polyfill'

plugins:[{ src: '@/plugins/poly', ssr: true }]
```

polyfill-eventsource added missing EventSource to window
SCRIPT1002: 语法错误
app.js (1691,89088)

Comment: Please make an effort on your question.

Comment: I found that the problem description starts with `ie9`, are you having this problem in IE 9? Can you provide more details, such as a minimal sample code that can reproduce this issue?